# Simple run of Angular2 throws an error with es6-promise .Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, es6-promise

I am trying to run Angular 2 Alpha 45 ('https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.45/angular2.dev.js') but it fails at the "es6Promise._setAsap" saying that es6Promise is undefined.

```
var es6Promise = require('es6-promise').Promise;

// es6-promise asap should schedule microtasks via zone.scheduleMicrotask so that any
// user defined hooks are triggered
es6Promise._setAsap(function(fn, arg) {
  global.zone.scheduleMicrotask(function() {
    fn(arg);
  });
});
```

The current page is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <script src="javascripts/system.js"></script>
        <script>
          System.config({
            map: {
                'es6-shim':'javascripts/es6-shim.js',
                'angular2/angular2': 'javascripts/lib/angular2.alpha.45.dev.js'
            }
          });
            System.import('es6-shim').then(function(){
                System.import('javascripts/app.js');
            });

        </script>            
    </head>    
    <body>
        <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
    </body>
</html>
```

The app.js contains the conversion of the example file which contains:

```
import {Component, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App b</h1>'
})
class AppComponent { }
bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

The question is:
Why does require('es-promise') returns an empty object?
I'm using simple typescript export of the app.js, and nothing else than the systemjs that angular.io talks about.

I think I'm missing something, maybe a ES6 shim or another version of angular2 for the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With another hour of search, apparently - and I don't know why it's not clearly stated in the current documentation of Angular - there was a **problem of SystemJs configuration**:

It was missing the fact that angular2 is using a specific format inside their script, and you have to explicitly set it.

**Final script in HTML code looks like this:**

```
<script src="javascripts/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/system.js"></script>
<script>
    System.config({
        paths:{"*":"../*.js"},
        map: {
            'angular2/angular2': 'javascripts/lib/angular2.dev',
            'crypto':'javascripts/crypto'
        },
        meta: {
            'angular2/angular2':{
                format: 'register'
            }
        }
    });
    System.import('javascripts/app');
</script>
```

Additional info:

- I think that the info from angular.io was for an older version of SystemJs (maybe the 16 because it really differs from the 19 that I've used here), I thought CommonJS was used inside Angular, but SystemJs warned me that it found things like "System.register" in the code so I changed the format to "register" (compatibility module format).
- Don't forget to add the system-pollyfill if you want it to work on old browsers